# C++ How to avoid array of function pointers for derived objects?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, derived-class

I have a base class **color**. I would like to have an different derived class for every color. When I transverse the enumeration, in case to avoid the if, else if situation for every derived class, I created an array of function pointers to create every time the appropriate object ( red, blue etc ).
But, at the end, I still have function pointers to do my job, even if in C++, it is supposed that they are not needed. Is there a way to avoid it, but without having an if, else if situation?

```
enum colors {
RED = 0,
BLUE,
GREEN,
.....,
.....,
.....,
.....,
.....,
.....,
.....,
.....,
MAX
};

class color {
    public:
        virtual void whatever() const {}
};
class red : public color {
    public:
        virtual void whatever() const {}
};
class blue : public color {
    public:
        virtual void whatever() const {}
};
class green : public color {
    public:
        virtual void whatever() const {}
};

template < class T >
static color const* make() { return new T(); }

color const* ( *array[MAX] )() = { make<red>, make<blue>,make<green>....};

int main ()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i ) {
        color const* i_color = (*array[i])();
            i_color->whatever();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need a class for each color?

Comment: Why do you want each color to be its own type?  This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You have an array of pointers to factory functions which you access by index. What do you want instead of that?

Comment: If it is a genuine need, you can template a class by your enum: `template<color C> class bobafett {}; bobafett<RED> red_bobafett;`

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, each color has it's own functionality. Obviously...the real problem has nothing to do with colors.

Comment: I think it's the right approach.

Comment: @0x5453 Yes, each color has it's own functionality

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin: I like the code as it is. BUT, it is said that with C++ you don't need function pointers, because you have the inheritance. But in this problem, if I don't have the function pointers, I must have an ugly if/else if/else if.... for each color.

Comment: @dkmg If you want to access those functions by index then this is the right solution. Not sure though why you want a class for each color, rather than one class with color as its member. With 24-bit color you end up with `2^^24` color classes. That is a lot of typing.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin: it's not a "color" problem. It's a structural engineer problem. Each "structure" has its own functionality. So I need a different function for each type of structure.

Comment: @YSC I don't understand the one you write. Could you please describe it a bit more?

Comment: @dkmg If it's not about color, you should have went with `foo` `bar` etc. to avoid a half dozen comments about how you shouldn't have a class for each color.  As far as the array of function pointers, you don't have to use them at all.  You can use [functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) instead.  Have a look at [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [`std::function<returnType(argTypes)>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). The first creates functors and the second is a generic functor holder.

Comment: You will get better answers if you describe your actual problem.